# How to get this checkbox filter code to work?

Tags: arrays, sorting, checkbox, vuejs3, pinia

I am trying to get this checkbox filter to return the "filteredTracks"

Here is the script:

```
<script setup>
import SongRow from "../components/SongRow.vue";
import Magnify from "../components/Magnify.vue";
import Play from "../components/Play.vue";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const selectedGenres = ref([])
const selectedMoods = ref([])
const selectedTempos = ref([])
const selectedThemes = ref([])
const search = ref('')

const filteredTracks = computed(() => {
```

This was how I solved this for anyone with the same issue... Just repeat the checkboxes for selectedMoods, selectedTempos, selectedThemes.